# Is negative of a concave function convex? What is the relationship between convex set and convex function?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, linear-programming, convex-geometry

Let *f* be a function of a single variable defined on the interval I.

Then *f* is:

concave if for all *a* ∈ I, all *b* ∈ I, and all *λ* ∈ (0, 1) we have
*f*((1−*λ*)*a* + *λb*)   ≥  (1 − *λ*)*f*(*a*) + *λf*(*b*)

convex if for all *a* ∈ I, all *b* ∈ I, and all *λ* ∈ (0, 1) we have
*f*((1−*λ*)*a* + *λb*)   ≤  (1 − *λ*)*f*(*a*) + *λf*(*b*)

My question is, if we take a concave function like the picture below, and take the negative of it, will it become convex? Since the appearance will be U-shaped just like a convex function. I understand that the inequality for concave function still holds if we negate the function. But I am curious from the visual point of view, why do we still call it concave since it looks like a convex function?

For my second question, the convex set can be visualized by connecting any two points in a set that still entirely belongs to the set. How does this relate to the definition of convex functions?

[image]

Comment: "I understand that the inequality for concave function still holds if we negate the function." Replacing $f$ with $-f$ in the inequality definitions of convexity/concavity swaps them, due to having to reverse the inequality sign when multiplying by $-1$. Is that what you understand? I'm not sure what you want in terms of a "visual" proof here.

Comment: I see a lot of content (online, books, lectures) where it is told that convex functions are those which have an upward bowl shape, whereas concave functions have a downward bowl shape. So is this statement kind of like a "naive" approach to recognizing convex/concave functions and not always true then?

Comment: @T_k . If your own picture does not already convince yourself, please try to show formally that $f$ is convex if and only if $-f$ is concave. In other words: the concept of a concave function is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the second question:

- The function $f$ is convex if and only if the set $S_f:=\{(x,y): y\ge f(x)\}$ is convex.

Proof of the if-part: take $x_1<x_2\,$ and write.
$$
\boldsymbol{v}_1:=\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\f(x_1)\end{pmatrix}\,,\quad \boldsymbol{v}_2:=\begin{pmatrix}x_2\\f(x_2)\end{pmatrix}\,.
$$
Because $S_f$ is convex, $a\boldsymbol{v}_1+(1-a)\boldsymbol{v}_2\in S_f$ for all $a\in[0,1]$. We can write this as
$$\tag{1}
af(x_1)+(1-a)f(x_2)\ge f\Big(ax_1+(1-a)x_2\Big)\,
$$
in other words, $f$ is convex.

Proof of the only-if-part:  Let $\boldsymbol{v}_1=\begin{pmatrix}\boldsymbol{v}_{11}\\\boldsymbol{v}_{12}\end{pmatrix}$ and $\boldsymbol{v}_2=\begin{pmatrix}\boldsymbol{v}_{21}\\\boldsymbol{v}_{22}\end{pmatrix}$ be two points in $S_f$. This means that
$$\tag{2}
\boldsymbol{v}_{12}\ge f(\boldsymbol{v}_{11})\,,\quad\boldsymbol{v}_{22}\ge f(\boldsymbol{v}_{21})
$$
Since $f$ is convex we have for any $a\in[0,1]$,
$$\tag{3}
af(\boldsymbol{v}_{11})+(1-a)f(\boldsymbol{v}_{21})\ge f\Big(a\boldsymbol{v}_{11}+(1-a)\boldsymbol{v}_{21} \Big)\,.
$$
From (2) and (3),
$$\tag{4}
a\boldsymbol{v}_{12}+(1-a)\boldsymbol{v}_{22}\ge f\Big(a\boldsymbol{v}_{11}+(1-a)\boldsymbol{v}_{21} \Big)\,,
$$
in other words, $a\boldsymbol{v}_1+(1-a)\boldsymbol{v}_2\in S_f$ and $S_f$ is convex.